# How to create an API which crawls a specific webpage

Tags: javascript, web-crawler

I want to design/create an API which crawls the data on a webpage  (webpage link will be provided as input) and returns the data in JSON/xml format.

I am looking for some help so that I can start looking in a particular direction.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but if you just want to parse input HTML page and get outlinks from it, you can do following

1. Get the HTML page as input stream
2. Create a DOM outof it using jtidy or any other HTML DOM parser.
3. Once you have a DOM, get all

   , href,  elements and you will have all the outlinks.

In general when you say crawling, it should involve multiple pages, in a graph and you move on from one page to another using these links. So crawling specific page is not correct.